# C# Snake game with no collision edges

Tags: c#

I'm doing a school project and I've chosen to make a snake game in C#.
I'm almost done with the game, but there is one last thing I would like to add and that is to have no collision when the snake hits one og th edges. So instead of the snake dying I want it to come out on the other end of the screen (as it was on the original game). Here's my code for when the snake hits the edge.

```
//Get maximum X and Y Pos
int maxXPos = pbCanvas.Size.Width / Settings.Width;
int maxYPos = pbCanvas.Size.Height / Settings.Height;

//Detect collission with game borders.
if (Snake[i].X < 0 || Snake[i].Y < 0
                   || Snake[i].X >= maxXPos || Snake[i].Y >= maxYPos)
{
    Die();
}
```

I know that the `Die();` is not supposed to be there, but I can't figure out what I should write there instead. I'm writing in Visual Studio 2010 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the modulus `%` operator for this:

```
Snake[i].X = (Snake[i].X + maxXPos) % maxXPos;
Snake[i].Y = (Snake[i].Y + maxYPos) % maxYPos;
```

Say for example `maxXPos == 10`, when the `X` becomes `-2`, this will make it `8`.

And when `X` becomes `11`, this will make it `1`.

Comment: Why `(Snake[i].X + maxXPos) % maxXPos;` and not just `Snake[i].X % maxXPos;`?

Comment: to avoid getting a negative result

Comment: Wouldn´t this return zero when the current position is zero for either X or Y? E.g. X = 0 --> (X + 10) % 10 = 0

Comment: I think zero is a valid position. If it isn't, `minXPos` could be defined as 1 to use as offset.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to handle each of the four cases and set the coordinates of the snake to the "opposite" location:

```
if(Snake[i].X < 0) Snake[i].X = maxXPos;
else if(Snake[i].X >= maxXPos) Snake[i].X = 0;
else if(Snake[i].Y < 0) Snake[i].Y = maxYPos;
else if(Snake[i].Y >= maxYPos) Snake[i].Y = 0;
```

The `else`-statements instead of simple `if` avoid that you make unnecessary comparisons when there already was some hit on any of the previos conditions.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. :)

Comment: This *might* give false positions, if your `Snake` can go faster than 1 element per turn. As long as the speed does not change, it should work out fine.

Comment: @DIF I´ve never seen a snake-game doing this. However the framerate may increase making the time for one single step smaller. But I can´t see any reason to make the snake "jump" several steps a time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should be used as you will always deal with only one collision:

```
//Get maximum X and Y Pos
int maxXPos = pbCanvas.Size.Width / Settings.Width;
int maxYPos = pbCanvas.Size.Height / Settings.Height;

//Detect collission with game borders.
if (Snake[i].X < 0 ){
    Snake[i].X = maxXPos;
}
else if(Snake[i].Y < 0){
    Snake[i].Y = maxYPos;
}
else if(Snake[i].X >= maxXPos){
    Snake[i].X = 0;
}
else if(Snake[i].Y >= maxYPos){
    Snake[i].Y = 0;
}
```

Comment: What I meant by that is the fact that in a single position update snake will only be going in one direction meaning that he will be able to only collide with one edge of the screen at a time. This is why else if's should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you also have min positions stored somewhere?

```
int maxXPos = pbCanvas.Size.Width / Settings.Width;
int maxYPos = pbCanvas.Size.Height / Settings.Height;

// Detect collission with game borders.
if (Snake[i].X < 0) { Snake[i].X = maxXPos; }
if (Snake[i].X > maxXPos 0) { Snake[i].X = 0; }
if (Snake[i].Y < 0) { Snake[i].Y = maxXPos; }
if (Snake[i].Y > maxYPos 0) { Snake[i].Y = 0; }
```